# copy and paste data in Datagridview control

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview, windows

Is there any way I can make datagridview control so that user can copy and paste more than one cell from excel by using `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` ?

Comment: I am a beginner, so haven't been able to try so much, tried to find online but not been able to find a solution that tell what exactly I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get **simple** Excel content by calling `Clipboard.GetText()` it will return a string.

In it the rows will be separated by `Linefeeds` (\r\n) and the fields by `Tabs` (\t).

Look at the code below, this will give you something to work with..:

```
    // Before you press the button copy some excel cells!
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("one", "one");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("two", "two");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("three", "three");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("four", "four");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("five", "five");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);

        dataGridView1.Focus();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 1];
        string s = Clipboard.GetText();
        string[] lines = s.Replace("\n", "").Split('\r');
        string[] fields;
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        foreach (string l in lines)
        { 
            fields = l.Split('\t');
            foreach (string f in fields)
                dataGridView1[column++, row].Value = f;
            row++;
            column = 0;
        }

    }
```

Pasting with Control-V is trickier, start with a button!

It would involve capturing the Control-V and processing it; this can be a bit hard to debug, though..